# Finding Number Of Permutation Reverses

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What is the easiest way to count the number of opposite order in permutation.

meaning the total of elements in the permutation where $i<j$ and $\sigma_i>\sigma_j$

For example, $3142$, we have $31, 32, 42,$ so $OO(3142)=3$.

Comment: There is only one way to count, and that is by... counting. So the easiest way (which also the hardest way) to count them is by... well... counting them.

Comment: Note that this quantity is sometimes called the *disorder* of a permutation.

Comment: It is also used to determine the parity of permutation